# Why does "this" gets different values?

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

```
var foo = {
    data: "a",
    print: function() {console.log(this.data)}
}

element.addEventListener("click", function(){foo.print()});
```

In this case context is foo object

```
element.addEventListener("click", foo.print);
```

When in this one it's `element`

Why is it so?

Comment: There are hundreds of articles here and on the net regarding `this` and `scope`. They would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by the way a function is called. In the first case, the "print" function is called via a property reference from the object "foo". Therefore, the value of `this` is a reference to that object.

In the second case, you've passed the reference to the "print" function to the system when setting up the event handler. Event handlers are invoked with `this` set to refer to the element involved in the event.

In your first example, the value of `this` in the anonymous function will also be a reference to the clicked element. You could transmit that to the "print" function if you wanted to:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(){ foo.print.call(this); });
```

Comment: I see, yours is also downvoted. I don't know what is wrong in our answers :'(

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
foo.print
```

you will be getting a reference to the function, but the function is actually attached to `foo` object which is lost by passing the `foo.print`. So, `print` becomes an unbound function. You can confirm this like this.

```
var a = foo.print;
a();                  // `this` will be referring to global now
```

To avoid this, you should [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function with the object, like this

```
element.addEventListener("click", foo.print.bind(foo));
```

Now we are making sure that the function is bound to the `foo` object. You can check this, like this

```
var a = foo.print.bind(foo);
a();                  // a
```

Comment: Downvoter please let me know how I can improve this answer.